# How to instantiate templated functors F<D> over multiple functors F1,F2 and multiple template parameters D1,D2?

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, metaprogramming, functor

I need to instantiate a bunch of functors

```
template<typename DataType>
struct Functor1{
   int a;
   Functor1(int a_){ a = a_; }
//    __device__
   void operator()(DataType &elem) 
       elem.x +=1;
   }
};

template<typename DataType>
struct Functor2{
   int a;
   Functor2(int a_){ a = a_; }
//    __device__
   void operator()(DataType &elem) {
       elem.x +=10;
   }
};
```

for Cuda by a set of structs `D1, D2...`:

```
struct D1{
    int x;
};
struct D2{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

I want **automatically** and **explicitly** instantiate all of them:

```
template class Functor1<D1>;
template class Functor1<D2>;
template class Functor2<D1>;
template class Functor2<D2>;
```

I want a macros/metaprogrammic trick the code above:

```
#define DATATYPE_LIST(D1)(D2)
#define FUNCTOR_LIST (Functor1)(Functor2)
EXPLICIT_FUNCTOR_INSTANTIATION(FUNCTOR_LIST, DATATYPE_LIST)
```

How to do that using macroses or SFINAE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want a macros/**metaprogrammic** trick the code above

Here is a way to do this using templates instead of macros. The below program works for arbitrary number of `Functor`s and `D`s. See the different instantiations at the end of this answer, for different combinations of `Functor`s and `D`s. This uses [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) features like `constexpr if` and *fold expression*.

```
template<template<typename>typename Functor, template<typename>typename... Functors, typename... Args> void f(Args... args)
{
    int i = (Functor<Args>(55)(args),...,1); //instantiate for the first parameter Functor with all of args
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Functors)>0)
    {
         f<Functors...>(args...);           //call recursively for remaining Functors with all of args
    }  
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test 1: "<< std::endl;
    f<Functor1, Functor2>(D1(), D2());
    std::cout <<"--------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Test 2: "<< std::endl;
    f<Functor1, Functor2, Functor3>(D1(), D2());
    std::cout <<"--------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Test 3: "<< std::endl;
    f<Functor1, Functor2>(D1(), D2(), D3());
    std::cout <<"--------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Test 4: "<< std::endl;
    f<Functor1, Functor2, Functor3>(D1(), D2(), D3());
    std::cout <<"--------------------------------------" << std::endl;
}
```

[Working demo c++17](https://godbolt.org/z/E8b8rb3eq)

---

Below are given(output of the above program) the instantiations that will be generated due to different call expressions.

```
Test 1: 
template Functor1<D1>
template Functor1<D2>
template Functor2<D1>
template Functor2<D2>
--------------------------------------
Test 2: 
template Functor1<D1>
template Functor1<D2>
template Functor2<D1>
template Functor2<D2>
template Functor3<D1>
template Functor3<D2>
--------------------------------------
Test 3: 
template Functor1<D1>
template Functor1<D2>
template Functor1<D3>
template Functor2<D1>
template Functor2<D2>
template Functor2<D3>
--------------------------------------
Test 4: 
template Functor1<D1>
template Functor1<D2>
template Functor1<D3>
template Functor2<D1>
template Functor2<D2>
template Functor2<D3>
template Functor3<D1>
template Functor3<D2>
template Functor3<D3>
--------------------------------------
```

This also works for *asymmetric* call expressions like: `f<Functor1, Functor2, Functor3>(D1(), D2(), D3(), D4());` etc.

Comment: Dear @Jason Liam, It is a very good solution, thank you very much! Since I need to instantiate it not in the main function, but inside .cu or .cpp file, then it can be instantiated as `template void f<Functor1, Functor2>(D1, D2);` outside functions.

Comment: @Jasib Liam, it is my fault:) I am just added comment for other readers, if they would like to instantiate outside of the main funciton.

Comment: @EugeneW. I see. Yes your comment might be helpful to future readers. So i've removed my other comments.

Comment: @EugeneW. I've made the method more compact. Check out my updated answer. It is much more clean and readable than before. [Demo updated method](https://godbolt.org/z/G4xx6jhfP).

Answer (score 1):

For that I implemented small macros which use boost for_each_product preprocessor:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_product.hpp>

#define MACRO_EXPLICIT_FUNCTOR_INSTANTIATION(r, product) template class BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, product)<BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, product)>;
#define EXPLICIT_FUNCTOR_INSTANTIATION(functor_list, datatype_list) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT(MACRO_EXPLICIT_FUNCTOR_INSTANTIATION, (functor_list)(datatype_list))

EXPLICIT_FUNCTOR_INSTANTIATION(FUNCTOR_LIST, DATATYPE_LIST)
```

If you compile with the flag -E you will see:

```
template class Functor1<D1>; template class Functor1<D2>; template class Functor2<D1>; template class Functor2<D2>;
```

Enjoy in the [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3dxa31fon) (be sure that boost library is added)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) version that uses [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) with `enable_if` to achieve the given task.

```
//for ending recursion
template<template<typename>typename Functor, typename... Args> void f(Args... args)
{
    
    const int i[] = {0, (Functor<Args>(55)(args), 0)...}; 
}
template<template<typename>typename Functor, template<typename>typename... Functors, typename... Args> typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Functors)>0)>::type f(Args... args)
{
   const int i[] = {0, (Functor<Args>(55)(args), 0)...}; //instantiate for the first parameter Functor with all of args
    
    f<Functors...>(args...);           //call recursively for remaining Functors with all of args
     
}

int main()
{
    
    f<Functor1, Functor2, Functor3>(D1(), D2(), D3()); //lets confirm if it works   
}
```

[Working demo c++11](https://godbolt.org/z/hvb91K6ET)

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
template <class D> struct functor1 {
  int a;
  auto operator ()(D& e) const noexcept { e.x += 1; }
};

// Types used must be COMPLETE (ie: DEFINED) before instantiation.
struct D1 { int x; };
struct D2 { int x, y; };

// Explicit *class/struct* template instantiation.
template struct functor1<D1>;
template struct functor1<D2>;
// I believe the 'struct' keyword isn't optional here. (But it's 2200hrs on Monday)
```

[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/srxP5qK7r)

Comment: In a question I implied that we have an unknown number of DataTypes D1, D2, ...DN and unknown number of functors functor1, functor2, .. functorN. And the question is how to automate it.